# Update 1bn rows in Amazon RDS Postgres Database

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-aurora

What would be the best way to update all records in a large Amazon RDS Postgres Database with 1bn rows? The update logic needs to run in code e.g NodeJS. We also want to keep track of progress, errors and avoid to much manual work since we expect this to take quite some time to execute.

I have been thinking of some task queue in SQS as a trigger for a Lambda running the code. Where each task covers a small range of the rows.

Comment: Is this a one-time update, or rather something which would be occurring often in production?

Comment: Sort of one time yes

Comment: Well at the very least, you should do some research and find out when your system is least used, and target that window as the time to do the update.  If I recall correctly, I have actually been on similar systems with Postgres and billions of records.  We basically couldn't do an update, because it would freeze the entire system.

Comment: Instead of doing an Update, could you possibly transform the data into a new table (possibly a subset at a time)? Once complete, you could then truncate and copy the data to the original table, or simply rename tables. Or is it "live data" that is changing during this update process?